# Chrome WebDriver On Mac IllegalStateException After Setting Webdriver.Chrome.Driver property

Tags: java, macos, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a properties file that i use to load the location of the different install locations for chrome:

```
mac.chrome="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
win.xp.chrome="%HOMEPATH%\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
win.7.chrome="C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
linux.chrome="//usr//bin//google-chrome"
```

I read these in, and as debug when i set the webdriver.chrome.driver prop i log it:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", (String)props.get("mac.chrome"));
log.logInfo("Mac Chrome Driver Property Set To: " + System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
```

logger output:

```
INFO: Mac Chrome Driver Property Set To: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
```

When i execute my test i see the below error:

```
[junit] The driver executable does not exist: /Users/<user>/eclipseproject/automation/com/gui/"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
[junit] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/<user>/eclipseproject/automation/com/gui/"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
[junit]     at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:117)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:112)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:75)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
[junit]     at drivermanager.DriverManagement.initializeDriver(DriverManagement.java:46)
[junit]     at tests.TestChromeChrome.setUp(TestAlerts.java:44)
```

I see in the error that the absolutePath is published, which makes sense as DriverService.checkExecutable does an exe.getAbsolutePath() call, but i don't understand why the path to my project is also included.  If anyone have any suggestions that would be awesome!

Comment: You are misunderstanding what you are being asked to pass in. You should not be passing in the **Chrome** location, but the **ChromeDriver** location (unless they are in the same place, that is).

Comment: @Arran setting the property webdriver.chrome.driver is the location to the chrome executable. What am i missing?

Comment: oh... i see.  I downloaded the driver, put it in path /users/<user>/downloads, set that as my webdriver.chrome.driver property, but i still see issue:  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: `

Answer (score 1):

Needed to setup the proper DesiredCapabilities object for chrome before the browser started to launch correctly. Also needed to remove the "" from my properties file (which resolved the IllegalStateException).